# Why am I only getting one value returned for my latitude and longitude? (For loop issue)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, object

```
def stn_list(self, state):

  self.state = state

  stn_list= self.client.service.getStations(stateCds= self.state, 
                               networkCds='SCAN',
                               logicalAnd=True)

  meta_data = self.client.service.getStationMetadataMultiple(stn_list)
  self.latitude = []
  self.longitude = []

  for meta in meta_data:
    self.latitude.append(meta.latitude)
    self.longitude.append(meta.longitude)

return(stn_list,meta.latitude, meta.longitude)
```

This is a small snippet of my overall code but basically I am trying to get a list of latitudes and longitudes to be returned along with each of the stations listed for when a user inputs a state name. While this works just fine for stn_list (the list of stations), latitude and longitude only returns one value, even though I am initializing an empty list and appending to the list.

Here is what I get which the current code if I wanted stations for Mississippi:

```
data2.stn_list('MS')

(['2032:MS:SCAN',
  '2024:MS:SCAN',
  '2025:MS:SCAN',
  '2110:MS:SCAN',
  '2087:MS:SCAN',
  '2033:MS:SCAN',
  '2046:MS:SCAN',
  '2109:MS:SCAN',
  '2070:MS:SCAN',
  '2086:MS:SCAN',
  '2064:MS:SCAN',
  '2082:MS:SCAN',
  '2034:MS:SCAN',
  '2035:MS:SCAN'],
 Decimal('34.06667'),
 Decimal('-90.35000'))
```

I should be getting 14 lats and lons not 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement is wrong - you're only returning a single latitude/longitude from the last `meta` iterated over.

```
return (stn_list, meta.latitude, meta.longitude)
```

should be

```
return (stn_list, self.latitude, self.longitude)
```

Comment: Wow that's all it was, thank you so much!